# Python CJKLIB: no pinyin tones

Tags: python, cjk

I'm working with CJKLIB, using the `getReadingForCharacter`, to convert Chinese characters into pinyin. However, is there some way

```
readings = cjk.getReadingForCharacter(c, 'Pinyin')
```

The problem is that it returns pinyin with the tones on them, which I do not want. For example, I want "Beijing", not "Běijīng" - with all the tone marks.

Anyone know how I can get an output without the tones? Thanks!

Comment: One option would be to strip the diacritics since there is a limited number of them.

Comment: How does one "strip" the diacritics? Just a global find / replace after I'm done?

Answer (score 2):

The solution simply is:

```
>>> cjk.getReadingForCharacter(u'北', 'Pinyin', toneMarkType='none')
[u'bei']
```

You can read more about possible options here: http://cjklib.org/0.3/library/cjklib.reading.operator.PinyinOperator.html#cjklib.reading.operator.PinyinOperator

Answer (score -1):

Maybe using a simpler lib fit your task better and faster, cjklib don't provide an API to convert chinese to pinyin without tone.

such python lib is as follows:

- [hanzi2pinyin](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/hanzi2pinyin/0.1)
- [xpinyin](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xpinyin/0.4.1)